# How can I connect to an IP address to access database in php

Tags: php, database, ms-access, odbc

How can I connect to xxxx file on a local network ?

```
SUCCESS
    $dbName =  "C:\db.mdb";
    if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
        die("Could not find database file.");
    }
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
    $sql  = "SELECT * ";
    $sql .= "  FROM table1";
    print "<TABLE border='1'>";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {

print "<tr>";
print "<td>" . $row["a1"]. " </td>";
print "<td>" . $row["a2"]." </td>";
print "<td>" . $row["a3"]." </td>";
print "</tr>";
}
echo "</TABLE>";
```

I have the same file from a

> different computer

you want to connect to an

> IP address

... 
How can I do it ?

Comment: Just like you'd access any other file: Windows share, NFS, whatever. Access itself does not include any network protocol on its design.

Answer (score 0):

Your Make Shared Folder -->properties-->Sharing-->Share This Folder On Network
YourFolder Share in Your Ip 
Like

$dbName =  "\192.168.1.4\my fodler\Databse.mdb";